# Set Listbox selection as variable

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I want to create something like a "Patch" file which I can send to users and they use it to patch their existing templates.

What I'm trying to do is to have a userform with a listbox that shows all currently opened Excel files, users then select the file they want to patch and click a button to run the patch script.

Am very new to userforms and vba as a whole, and am having difficulty trying to set the 'Listbox1.Selection' as a variable that the subsequent patch code can refer to. My code currently for the userform/listbox is as below (It just allows selection of item:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks
    If Windows(wb.Name).Visible Then _
      ListBox1.AddItem wb.Name
Next

End Sub
```

Once users select the file, how do I go about setting that as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I go about setting that as a variable?**

```
Private Sub doPatch()
With Me.ListBox1
    Dim currIndex&
    currIndex = .ListIndex             ' assign zerobased index number to variable

    ' how do I go about setting that as a variable?
      Dim currWB
      currWB = .List(currIndex, 0)     ' get chosen list element in column zero based on current index

    ' 'or simply:
    ' currWB = .Value                  ' sufficient in your case as only one column listed

    ' display both variables in immediate window of your VB Editor
      Debug.Print "zerobased Listindex#: " & currIndex & " ~> " & currWB

    ' do patch stuff...

End With
End Sub
```

Eventually ou could call the above procedure either by a command button and/or by doubleclick, e.g. via

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    doPatch
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    doPatch
End Sub
```

Comment: So the first set of script sets the listbox selection as a variable, while the second set of script would run the "patch" script using the variable set?

Comment: Yes, for use within the `doPatch` procedure; if you want it for use within the Userform Code module you'll have to declare the variable outside, i.e. on top of the code module (declaration head, e.g. after `Option Explicit`): `Dim currIndex&` or `Dim currIndex As Long` and execute only the assignment within the procedure. - Feel free to mark my above answer as accepted by marking the green check mark if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Command button to your UserForm and add the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.Text


End Sub
```

That will print the Selected option to the A1. You can save it to variable to anything further you want.

Basically `ListBox1.Text` will give you the selected option.

Comment: This will set the workbook name as text in A1 range, but how would I be able to call it when I need to run the script for patching the "report" workbook?

Comment: Just use `var_name = Activesheet.Range("A1").Value` ....Now you will have the name in var_name which is your variable. You can assign this in your Patch Code or anywhere else, name of the sheet won't go anywhere, you can read it in any code using the above statement. @SimoKeng